# encrypting the data being stored in my database

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

i am currently using nodejs as my backend, sequelize ORM and postgres as my db.

When my user is signing up, i am trying to encrypt the data using the builtin crypto module.

everything is working but since i am generating a custom IV, the encrypted data all take the same IV since it is rendered every time node restarts. How do i give each field a different IV?

This is my first time encrypting data, can someone tell me if what i am doing is correct or not?

```
let key ="12345678123456781234567812345678";
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

router.post(
 "/register",
 (req, res) => {
                                  
 let cipher1 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
 let cipher2 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
 let cipher3 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
 let cipher4 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
 let cipher5 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);

 let mobilenumber = cipher1.update(req.body.mobilenumber);
 const encrypted_mobilenumber = Buffer.concat([mobilenumber, cipher1.final()]);

 let firstname = cipher2.update(req.body.firstname);
 const encrypted_firstname = Buffer.concat([firstname, cipher2.final()]);

 let lastname = cipher3.update(req.body.lastname);
 const encrypted_lastname = Buffer.concat([lastname, cipher3.final()]);

 let dob = cipher4.update(req.body.dob);
 const encrypted_dob = Buffer.concat([dob, cipher4.final()]);

 const fullAddress= req.body.housenumber + ', ' + req.body.address1 + 
                    (req.body.address2===''?'': ', ' + req.body.address2 ) + 
                   ', ' + req.body.city + ', ' + req.body.postcode + ', ' + req.body.country

 let address = cipher5.update(fullAddress);
 const encrypted_address = Buffer.concat([address, cipher5.final()]);
                                  
              User.create({
                            email: req.body.email,
                            mobilenumber:iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted_mobilenumber.toString('hex'),
                            passcode: req.body.passcode,
                            firstname:iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted_firstname.toString('hex'),
                            lastname:iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted_lastname.toString('hex'),
                            dob:iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted_dob.toString('hex'),
                            address:iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted_address.toString('hex')
                          })
```

Comment: If you don't want to reuse the IV (and you absolutely must not do that in CBC mode), then don't use a global variable, obviously. Call randomBytes for each encryption. Also consider using authenticated encryption with, say, AES-GCM-SIV.

Comment: Also, hex encoding is terrible because it doubles the data size. [Postgres can store binary data just fine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-binary.html) so you probably don't have to encode at all. Use base64, if anything, because it incurs "only" 33% overhead.

Comment: @Peter i am still new to encryption, can you example the difference between aes-256-cbc and AES-GCM-SIV? Also what do you mean by Postgres can store binary data?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JS library, but I imagine it's just replacing `aes-256-cbc` with `aes-256-gcm-siv` (even `aes-256-gcm` is better). // You don't have to turn the ciphertexts into printable text. Just store them as-is in columns of type bytea.

Comment: @Peter `You don't have to turn the ciphertexts into printable text. Just store them as-is in columns of type bytea` by this you mean i remove `.toString('hex')` in my create method?

Comment: Yes. Don't encode unless you have to (and I don't see why you would).

Comment: @Peter i so sorry but i am still new to encryption what do you mean by encoding exactly? And also, what do you mean by base64 only incurs 33% overhead?

Comment: @Peter do you suggest i do something like this instead https://gist.github.com/rjz/15baffeab434b8125ca4d783f4116d81?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can simplify this code by introducing a new function, encryptField(), that will encrypt a given field with the key provided and prepend the iv to it before returning.

I would also suggest creating a getFullAddress function to turn address components into the full address.

All of this should significantly reduce code length and duplication:

```
const key = "12345678123456781234567812345678";

function encryptField(data, key) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
    return iv.toString('base64') + ':' + Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data),cipher.final()]).toString("base64");
}

function getFullAddress({housenumber, address1, address2, city, postcode, country}) {
    return [housenumber, address1, ...(address2 ? [address2]: []), city, postcode, country].join(", ");
}

router.post(
    "/register",
    (req, res) => {
        User.create({
            email: encryptField(req.body.email, key),
            mobilenumber: encryptField(req.body.mobilenumber, key),
            passcode: req.body.passcode,
            firstname: encryptField(req.body.firstname, key),
            lastname: encryptField(req.body.lastname, key),
            dob: encryptField(req.body.dob, key),
            address: encryptField(getFullAddress(req.body), key)
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer will give it a try now, but other than the simplification, the encryption is correct? Also, do you suggest that i encrypt my key or encrypt the encrypted fields again?

Comment: The encryption is correct, you're using AES-256-CBC which is pretty strong. Key storage will be likely the weak point, this should be saved as a secret, and should not be readily available to an attacker.

Comment: Where should i store my Key? i need to upload it to the server using pm2 correct? Will it be available for attackers there? Also, as you can see i am passing the passcode from my frontend, should i encrypt it in my frontend before sending it to my backend?

Comment: If it's on your pm2 server it will be set as an environment variable, this will not be available to attackers, so it will be safe.

Comment: Thank you a lot Terry, after your help. Last 2 things i promise, you can see i am passing the passcode from my frontend, should i encrypt it in my frontend before sending it to my backend?

Comment: Hmmm, be careful about encrypting on the frontend, remember code running on the client side is visible to an attacker. If you're using HTTPS (which I assume you are), the connection to the backend will be encrypted in any case. So, this should not be necessary.

Comment: In my frontend i am passing the passcode from one screen to another, can that be intercepted? Also, can you check the comment on the question, i go suggested to use aes-256-gcm or AES-GCM-SIV as they are better than aes-256-cbc

Comment: Passing the passcode from one screen to another should be fine, it's all running on the same client. aes-256-gcm would be more secure, and should be almost as simple to implement.

Comment: if i change to aes-256-gcm will i need to change alot of stuff in my code?

Comment: aes-256-gcm will, in addition to encrypted data and IV also product an authTag, this will need to be stored somewhere as well, since it is necessary as part of decryption. An example is here: https://gist.github.com/rjz/15baffeab434b8125ca4d783f4116d81.

Comment: Thank you alot, i dont know what i would have done honestly without you. Thank you again. in the github example, i found this comment `// randomBytes here are (relatively) slow but convenient for demonstration`. what do you suggest i use instead of randomBytes? Also, will i be able to use the same functions as the ones you suggested above in your answer?

Comment: Oh I think randomBytes should be fine. It will probably take microseconds to generate the 16 bytes for the IV! You should be able to use the same functions,  just maybe with slight modification if using aes-256-gcm.

Comment: Will give it a try now and update you. thanks again :)

Comment: hey terry, another quick question, do you suggest i use hex to encode or base64? I am also using postgres as my database

Comment: Hey, I think base64 makes more sense, it will use less space than hex. There's no other reason to prefer hex over base64.

Comment: Do you mind updating the code above with base64, thank you. When should i use hex then?

Comment: I've updated the code to encode as base64, you can use either encoding really. Hex is more readable when you need to eyeball values, but it uses more space.

Comment: Oh i just change hex to base64 thats it, thanks. from the comments above, i got suggested this `You don't have to turn the ciphertexts into printable text. Just store them as-is in columns of type bytea` do you agree?

Comment: Yes you could store as bytes, it will be more space efficient again. But base64 would still work ok!

Comment: So encrypted can either be stored as bytes or base64 or hex, bytes being the most space efficient but this means ill need to change the datatype in my database from character varying to bytea as suggested correct

Comment: That's right, but it would be an easy migration to do!

Comment: So last thing i promise do you suggest i stay with base64 or use bytes? or it doesnt matter. thank you again legend

Comment: Honestly,  you can use either.  Using bytes is arguably more correct,  but base64 will work just fine!

Comment: If i decide to use bytes how will that change the code above? will i just need to remove both `toString('base64')` from the encryptField function and change my datatype in my db? Also, i can use this encryption to encrypt everything that gets stored in my database which i need to retrieve later?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how using bytes will work, you could return a buffer from encodeField, just concatenating the IV with the encrypted bytes. You can just play about with writing bytes to the db to test it!

Comment: Ok Perfect Thanks alot Terry for your time. Your current solution is working perfectly, but i am trying to implement `aes-256-gcm` with `base64` to the code above but it is not working, i have tried following the github link you suggested but i keep getting errors. if possible can you please add a new solution underneath the existing one using `aes-256-gcm` thank you alot again, i really appreciate your help and time :) :)

Comment: I have problem concatenating this `return [enc, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()];` i get this as a response `[
  '6i6XnHPWMZdMR7t3',
  <Buffer 70 27 e9 00 1f e5 fd 6a 16 a2 29 d8 4e 7c 64 c3>,
  <Buffer b9 a1 77 ae 10 ed 80 c4 1d bf 57 b6 b5 d4 7b 16>
]` and my database doesnt accept Arrays

Comment: I'd suggest changing enc to a buffer, then using Buffer.concat() on the array, that should give you a Buffer combining all the required data.

Comment: Is it ok to store a long buffer in my database?

Comment: A few hundred bytes will be fine,  even a few kb too!